# Add products to order programmatically magento admin

Tags: magento, admin

I have customized my create order page and in that after selecting customer and store id I have information of the product(Ex product A), I want that after admin reaches the sales_order_create then there must be that product(Product A) in the 'Items Ordered' list by default.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to add an observer for the event called "create_order_session_quote_initialized". In the observer you need to add something like this:

```
$session = $observer->getSession();
if ($session->getProductAdded()) {
    return $this;
}

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$session->getQuote()->addProduct($product);
$session->setProductAdded(true);

return $this;
```

It's not the exact code which already works. But I hope that this will help.

Comment: This is not working, i put this code at event "create_order_session_quote_initialized" but it throws an error "Call to a member function getProductAdded() on a non-object"

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake.The first line should be $session = $observer->getSessionQuote();

Comment: still giving error "Call to a member function getProductAdded()"

Answer (score 0):

First we need to initialize the quote with product(Product A).

```
$quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')
                ->setProduct($product)
                ->setQuote($this->getQuote())
                ->setQty($qty)
                ->setPrice($product->getPrice())
                ->save();
```

Convert this quote item to order item.

```
$orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/convert_quote')
    ->itemToOrderItem($quoteItem)
    ->save($this->getOrder->getId());
```